# AWS Cognito returning invalid signature with new userpool

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS Cognito user pool that is a replacement for an old one that I had to delete because of a custom attribute issue. I am using the same exact code as before though the keys have changed. I have them in a JSON file that I pulled from the AWS URL for getting the keys. I am getting an error now about `invalid signature` when trying to validate a JWT. I know my code is solid since it hasn't changed but was looking to see from others if there is something else I am missing or should do other than update my pool id, client id, and keys.json file.

Edit 2

I have resolved the issue by deleting and recreating the user pool - I use Terraform so it is quick and easy but also repeatable so this is the exact same config as before but now working

Edit adding my code just incase there is an issue with it though I can't see why if nothing changed

```
exports.isJWTValid = () => (req, res, next) => {
    let idToken = req.headers.authorization
    let token = idToken.split(' ')[1]
    let header = jwt_decode(token, { header: true });
    let keys = keysJSON.keys
    let kid = header.kid
    let jwk = keys.find(r => r.kid === kid)
    let pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
    jwt.verify(token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decodedToken) {
        if(err) { // error is showing up in this if(err) and returning to postman
            logger.debug(err) 
            return res.status(401).json({success: false, err})
        }
        const currentSeconds = Math.floor((new Date()).valueOf() / 1000)
        if (currentSeconds >= decodedToken.exp || currentSeconds < decodedToken.auth_time ) {
            let message = 'Session has expired, please login again.'
            return res.status(401).json({success: false, message});
        }
        if(decodedToken.aud !== config.ClientId) {
            let message = 'Token doen\'t match app client'
            return res.status(401).json({success: false, message});
        }
        if(decodedToken.iss !== `https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${config.UserPoolId}`) {
            let message = 'Token doen\'t match user pool'
            return res.status(401).json({success: false, message});
        }
        if(decodedToken.token_use !== 'id' && decodedToken.token_use !== 'access') {
            let message = 'Token use case doen\'t match'
            return res.status(401).json({success: false, message});
        }
        logger.debug('decodedToken: ', decodedToken)
        next()
    });
};
```